# Coordinates are not obtained after factory reset

Tags: android

My device have problem fetching coordinates of the current location after i did a factory reset.I have checked the Location services in settings and everything seems fine.

[image]

I have used the same code and it worked before i did factory reset.Below is my code to obtain coordinates

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
      mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {

   latitude =  loc.getLatitude();
   longitude =  loc.getLongitude();

    String Text = "My current location is: " +
    "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
    "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("lat and long "+Text);
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
  {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
  {

  }
}
```

Any suggestions to overcome this issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Location services work in another application? ex.: "GPS Test"

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Yes when i opened Maps Application the location is perfect.when i try codes from internet to get the coordinates it always returns null.

Comment: At which place are you getting null? You can also run your application on emulator and send from emulator mock coordinates to your app.

Comment: it works fine with emulator..when i run it in device latitude and longitude are null "loc.getLatitude(),getlongitude()".

Comment: very strange. NETWORK_PROVIDER returns also null?

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji yes..